# Odds and Evens Applications

Tags: java

I am  generating 25 random integers between 0 and 99. However I have to
display all the evens on one line and all the odds on the next line. How can I do it?

```
public class FindEvenOrOddNumber
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[100];
        for(int i=0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            numbers [i]  =  (int) (Math.random()*99) + 1;
            if(numbers[i]%2 == 0)
                System.out.println("EVEN:\n" +numbers[i] );
            else
                System.out.println("ODD:\n" +numbers[i] );
         }
     }
}
```

Output of the program would be:

```
EVEN: 92
EVEN: 18
ODD: 83
ODD: 37
ODD: 81
EVEN: 66
ODD: 37
EVEN: 18
EVEN: 4
ODD: 3
ODD: 63
ODD: 11
ODD: 73
ODD: 63
EVEN: 94
ODD: 51
EVEN: 32
EVEN: 60
ODD: 7
ODD: 35
ODD: 39
ODD: 51
EVEN: 12
EVEN: 8
EVEN: 76
```

Comment: Since this looks like homework, I don't think it's ethical to help you unless you're really stuck. This code looks like it will work, so all you need is a little more effort to get over the hump. You're almost there.

Comment: How are you going to generate 25 random integers from this ?

Comment: This text is basically just a statement. What is the actual problem you are facing with the code?

Comment: I have to display all the evens on one line and all the odds on the next line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Odd and Even Numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585212/odd-and-even-numbers)

Answer (score 3):

Use two loops. In both iterate over all numbers but in first test if number is even, if so print it, in second check if number is odd, if so print it.

Comment: I think you just helped OP with his/her homework. There's an easier way to do with changing just one or two lines in the existing sample.

Comment: @mttdbrd I also assume that this is homework question, that is why there are no code examples here, so OP will have to implement it on its own which definitely will help him/her learn about Java and probably algorithms.